# The good/better/best part of

Tags: meaning, idioms

1. The good part of the year.
2. The better part of the year.
3. The best part of the year.
4. The nice part of the year (If we say so).

What is the difference, if any?
My research:
According to the dictionaries, better/best part means the same thing, which I doubt.
The good part definition is vaguely similar.
And the nice part is something I have come up of my own.

Comment: *He was missing for **a** good part of the year.* ~ He was missing for a significant proportion of the year. He was missing for, probably, about 4 months -- *He was missing for the better part of the year.* ~ He was missing for over half a year -- *He was missing for the best part of the year.*  - He was missing for almost a year -- *The nice part of the year* – the part of the year that you like most

Answer (score -1):

They mostly mean the same thing - if you use 'good', 'better' or 'best' you are suggesting that the rest of the year is: not as good, worse, or great but not the best as the 'best' time of year, respectively.

However, they can mean slightly different things, depending on the context. The best part' is pretty straightforward - it is the best, full stop. The use of 'good' or 'better' may indicate that the year is not really that great in and of itself but there are times where it is bearable, more tolerable, and thus 'good'/'better'.

I would say that 'nice' can also be used to mean the same thing as 'good'/'better', however, it may be used specifically with reference to surroundings or environment - for example, spring time may be considered to be the nicest time of the year (because of how nice the weather is).

Comment: If you say that "John was gone for the _best part of_ the year", you don't mean he's missed the best bits, you mean he's been gone for a lengthy part of the year. So in that case you're talking quantity of time not quality.

Comment: To add to what @KillingTime said, the same applies to "better" - it may also be used to refer to the majority of something.

Comment: @KillingTime I think "better part" is a common idiom meaning majority, but I don't think I've heard "best part" used this way very much.